# celery one broker multiple queues and workers

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a python file called `tasks.py` in which I am defining 4 single tasks. I would like to configure celery in order to use 4 queues because each queue would have a different number of workers assigned. I was reading I should use **route_task** property but I tried several options and not a success.

I was following this doc [celery route_tasks docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing)

My goal would be run 4 workers, one for each task, and don't mix tasks from different workers in different queues. It's possible? It's a good approach?

If I am doing something wrong I would be happy to change my code to make it work

Here is my config so far

tasks.py

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')
app.conf.task_default_queue = 'default'
app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('queueA',    routing_key='tasks.task_1'),
    Queue('queueB',    routing_key='tasks.task_2'),
    Queue('queueC',    routing_key='tasks.task_3'),
    Queue('queueD',    routing_key='tasks.task_4')
)


@app.task
def task_1():
    print "Task of level 1"


@app.task
def task_2():
    print "Task of level 2"


@app.task
def task_3():
    print "Task of level 3"


@app.task
def task_4():
    print "Task of level 4"
```

Run celery one worker for each queue

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q queueA --logfile=celery-A.log -n W1&
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q queueB --logfile=celery-B.log -n W2&
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q queueC --logfile=celery-C.log -n W3&
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q queueD --logfile=celery-D.log -n W4&
```

Comment: Basically my problem was, a confusion with the documentation, I was using 3.x version and was using documentation of 4.x...epic fail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to get into complex routing for submitting tasks into different queues. Define your tasks as usual.

```
from celery import celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def task_1():
    print "Task of level 1"


@app.task
def task_2():
    print "Task of level 2"
```

Now while queuing the tasks, put the tasks in proper queue. Here is an example on how to do it.

```
In [12]: from tasks import *

In [14]: result = task_1.apply_async(queue='queueA')

In [15]: result = task_2.apply_async(queue='queueB')
```

This will put the `task_1` in queue named `queueA` and `task_2` in `queueB`.

Now you can just start your workers to consume them.

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q queueA --logfile=celery-A.log -n W1&
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q queueB --logfile=celery-B.log -n W2&
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: `task` and `message` are used interchangeably in the answer. It is basically a payload that the `producer` sends to RabbitMQ

You can either follow approach suggested by Chillar or you can define and use the `task_routes` configuration to route the messages to appropriate queue. This way you don't need to specify queue name every time you call `apply_async`.

Example: Route **task1** to `QueueA` and route **task2** to `QueueB`

```
app = Celery('my_app')
app.conf.update(
    task_routes={
        'task1': {'queue': 'QueueA'},
        'task2': {'queue': 'QueueB'}
    }
)
```

Sending a task to multiple queue is a bit tricky. You will have to declare an exchange, and then route your task with appropriate `routing_key`. You can get more information about type of exchange [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchanges). Let's go with `direct` for purpose of illustration.

1. Create Exchange

   ```
   from kombu import Exchange, Queue, binding
   exchange_for_queueA_and_B = Exchange('exchange_for_queueA_and_B', type='direct')
   ```
2. Create bindings on Queues to that exchange

   ```
   app.conf.update(
       task_queues=(
           Queue('QueueA', [
               binding(exchange_for_queueA_and_B, routing_key='queue_a_and_b')
           ]),
           Queue('QueueB', [
               binding(exchange_for_queueA_and_B, routing_key='queue_a_and_b')
           ])
       )
   )
   ```
3. Define the `task_route` to send **task1** to the exchange

   ```
   app.conf.update(
       task_routes={
           'task1': {'exchange': 'exchange_for_queueA_and_B', 'routing_key': 'queue_a_and_b'}
       }
   )
   ```

You can also declare these options of `exchange` and `routing_key` in your `apply_async` method as suggested by Chillar in the above answer.

After that, you can define your workers on same machine or different machines, to consume from those queues.

```
celery -A my_app worker -n consume_from_QueueA_and_QueueB -Q QueueA,QueueB
celery -A my_app worker -n consume_from_QueueA_only -Q QueueA
```